# Why can't I update Firestore string value in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a button, and when I press it I want it to update a null value with a string.  In the code, you will notice a future builder, and just know I need that to determine what I should exactly update depending on the data status in Firestore.  When a user is created the value of `isPledged` is set to null, but as you see by the if statement if that value is null, I want to update it with a string "true".  However, when I do so, nothing changes in Firestore with the value remaning null.  I'm a bit confused about where I messed up so any help would be much appreciated.  Also, I know I could remove the if statement but I'm going to add another option if the value does have data, so that's why that's there.

```
onPressed: () {
  FutureBuilder(
    future: getPledgedStatus(),
    builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      final CollectionReference
      users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserNames');
      FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      String uid = auth.currentUser.uid.toString();
      users.doc(uid).update(
        {'isPledged': "true"}
      );
    }

    },
  );
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
},
```

Comment: I think maybe because you convert the user's uid to string and firebase cannot detect that user id due to it being a string

Comment: @iKreateCode Sorry that didn't work.

Comment: code looks good; could you share your firestore doc path structure? Also validate the document ID by printing the `uid`.

Comment: @MuthuThavamani So I ran a few tests and came to the conclusion that something wrong must be with the Future Builder.  When I took the Future Builder away and instead directly had the document updated when pressed, the value did change.  When I put the same code back into the Future builder using the if statement to check if there was data or not, it failed to work.  What do you suggest I do?

Comment: i don't know what you are achieving here! I was thinking, what is the need for future builder inside a button click event? as you mentioned simple async function would have done the action!

Comment: @MuthuThavamani Well, I suppose I need the future since I have a value in firestore that will be toggled.  Basically i want to check if the user pledged or not, and I use a future to return that data and check its status.  Using the future in the button I was trying to get the current value state from firestore and using the if statement to determine what to do when the button is clicked.  If the data returned null, I tried to make it so that I could update it with a string value and then Navigate off that screen.  Otherwise is the data did not return null, something else would happen.

Comment: @MuthuThavamani Would a future then be a good thing to use in this situation or not?

Comment: @MuthuThavamani Actually you were right about simply using an async function, I missed that.  I wrote some new code and it works like a charm.  I'll post an answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so after Muthu Thavamani reminded me that I could simply use the async function instead of a future builder it worked, here's the new code:

```
onPressed: () async {
  try {
    final CollectionReference users = firestore.collection('UserNames');
    final String uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
    final result = await users.doc(uid).get();

    var isPledged = result.data()['isPledged'];

    if (isPledged == null) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserNames').doc(uid).update({
        "isPledged": "true",
      });
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    } else {
      //Something else
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted. So that, others can help with other questions.